# How numpy printoptions will work with images?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, computer-vision

I was trying to print an image to analyze, if there are some changes in the pixel intensities if the images are forged. Anyways my doubt is related  with the numpy.printoptions.
I was trying below code and numpy.printoptions was not working:
[Image of code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72mDp.png)
Code:

```
import numpy
import numpy as np
DIR = "D:/Work/ML/API/MNB/28 - Forgery/data/phase-01-training.tar/dataset-dist/chunks/1500_64_16"
TRAIN_CHUNKS = os.path.join(DIR, "train")
TRAIN_FAKE_CHUNKS = os.path.join(TRAIN_CHUNKS, "fake")
TRAIN_PRISTINE_CHUNKS = os.path.join(TRAIN_CHUNKS, "pristine")

IND=2000
train_chunk_files = os.listdir(TRAIN_FAKE_CHUNKS)
src = cv2.imread(os.path.join(TRAIN_FAKE_CHUNKS, train_chunk_files[IND]))
print(src[:, :, 1].shape)
with numpy.printoptions(threshold=64):
    ok = np.copy(src[:, :, 1])
    print(ok)
# print(src[:, :, 1])
plt.imshow(src)

plt.show()
```

But on the other end numpy printoptions is working fine for mnist dataset!!!
[Working code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNuuk.png)
code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(training_images, training_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=200)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(type(training_images[0]))
plt.imshow(training_images[0])
print(training_labels[0])
print(training_images[0])
```

What is the mistake I am doing over here? How to print the RGB image for each channel? I have checked the datatype for both of the image, it is numpy, ndarray.

Edit 1:
Things are not working by using linewidth.
[Code with linewidth in np.printoptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii9Qq.png)

Comment: shape of the image is: (64, 64, 3)

Answer (score 0):

From the diagram you have given in "Image of code snippet" link, it seems printoptions print the values in both cases, incase if the values needs to be printed properly (displaying all values), u could use,

```
    with np.printoptions(linewidth=200): 
        ok = np.copy(src[:, :, 1])
        print(ok)
```

if this is not what you are looking for, please let me know in the comments section. Happy to correct the answer!

Comment: No, Things are not working by changing it to linewidth.

Comment: I have edited the image with the code you have suggested.